# Cypress.io Iterate list of elements to see if text does not exist, then perform action to add element

Tags: loops, promise, conditional-statements, cypress, each

I'm trying to iterate over a list (<UL>) to see whether or not a specific string exists within the <li> list item elements.  If the string (Lemon in this example) does not exist then I want to perform an action to add the element. Otherwise, if the string does exist then I just want to do nothing and continue on.

Sample html:

```
<ul id=theTree>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried:

```
let found = false
cy.get('#theTree').find('li').each( ($node, i, $list) => {
  if ($node.textContent.includes("Lemon")) {
    found = true
  }
})
// At this point after each <li> has been iterated over, will 'found' be true or false?
if (!found) {
  // Add "Lemon" to the list here if it was not found in the <ul> list...
} else {
  // Do nothing. Lemon already exists in the list.
}
```

The if condition "$node.textContent" is returning undefined and not returning the text content from the list elements. Therefore, the .includes() function throws an error.

Also, I have feeling the asynchronous callback function from .each() needs a Promise or some other means of saving the "found = true" state, such that, the second if block can correctly determine whether or not "Lemon" was found in the list iteration.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps iterating with `.each()` is not the easiest way to do this.

Using `.then()` allows you to pass the `found` value down the chain. You could also add an alias if you want to use it later in the test.

Setting a variable external to the command chain is called a "backflip" and can cause problems depending on the test structure.

```js
cy.get('#theTree').find('li')
  .then($els => {
    const texts = [...$els].map(el => el.innerText)  // extract texts
    const found = texts.includes('Lemon')
    return found
  })
  .then(found => {
    if (!found) {
      ...
  })
```

With an alias

```js
cy.get('#theTree').find('li')
  .then($els => {
    const texts = [...$els].map(el => el.innerText)  // extract texts
    const found = texts.includes('Lemon')
    return found
  })
  .as('found')

// later

cy.get('@found').then(found => {
  if (!found) {
    ...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the result *after* the `each` command will be executed.
For instance, you can use `then` command as follows:

```js
let found = false
cy.get('#theTree').find('li').each( ($node, i, $list) => {
  if ($node.textContent.includes("Lemon")) {
    found = true
  }
}).then(() => {
// this callback will be executed after 'each' command so we know the result at this point.
if (!found) {
  // Add "Lemon" to the list here if it was not found in the <ul> list...
} else {
  // Do nothing. Lemon already exists in the list.
}
})
```